# Can we turn a In identity matrix into a In+1 identity matrix using only elementary matrix transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say I have a size 2 identity matrix I<sub>2</sub> = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
Could I turn it into a size 3 identity matrix I<sub>3</sub> = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
using only elementary matrix transformations?

Comment: What elementary matrix transformations do you know of?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is the context?

Comment: @Arthur 1. Interchanging the rows (columns) within the matrix 2. Scaling the entire row (column) with a non zero number 3. Add one row (column) to another row multiplied by a non zero number.

Comment: And do any of those change the shape or size of the matrix in any way?

Comment: It depends which "constructors" you "authorize". If "diag" operator is allowed; $I_3=diag(I_2,{1})$ (this would be possible in Matlab with "blkdiag").

Comment: @Arthur I forgot to mention that rows (columns) of zeroes can be added or removed. Although I don't fully understand under what circumstances which might be the crux of this issue.

Comment: @JeanMarie Only the operations on columns and rows mentioned in the reply to Arthur.

Comment: @asymptotic I was thinking about how we add scalars to matrixes. Say you have a function f(x) = x+5, if we were to enter a size 3 matrix into the equation we would also use a size 3 identity matrix to convert the 5 into a size 3 scalar matrix. However, if we entered a size 4 matrix then we would use a size 4 identity matrix to convert the 5 into a size 4 scalar matrix. This made me think that the size of identity matrixes doesn't really matter, which reminded me of matrix basis. They can be changed to a different size using elementary transformations without losing their properties.

Comment: $A_{3\times 2}\cdot I_2\cdot B_{2\times 3}=I_3\Rightarrow A\cdot B=I_3$.

Comment: @WindSoul Such matrices do not exist ; otherwise we would have a rank-2 matrix $A.B$ equal to a rank-3 matrix $I_3$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. Adding a row and column of zeros as you suggest gives

$$  \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$
No interchanging of rows/columns, scaling them by a nonzero number, or adding rows/columns will make that $I_3$.

Remember the elementary row operations preserve the solutions in a homogeneous system of equations.  The above matrix represents the homogeneous system $x_1=x_2=0,x_3\in \mathbb{R}$. However, $I_3$ represents the homogeneous system $x_1=x_2=x_3=0.$